# Do power laws work for kets and bras?

Tags: quantum-state

We know for two real numbers a and b

$$a^3 \times b^3=(ab)^3$$

What if a and b are ket and bra, respectively?

Can i write the below formula?

$$(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)^2(\langle0|+\langle1|)^2=(|0\rangle\langle0|+|0\rangle\langle1|+|1\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle1|)^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Laws of exponents work because they apply to multiplication of numbers, and multiplication is commutative. You can manipulate terms of an expression that has only numbers, multiplications and exponentiations due to this property.

Kets and bras are matrices of different dimensions, and matrix multiplication is not commutative.

To give the smallest example, $\langle 0|$ and $|0 \rangle$, $\langle 0|0 \rangle = 1$ (a number), and $|0 \rangle\langle 0| = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (a $2 \times 2$ matrix).

Adding more terms and higher powers will follow the same principle: depending on the terms and their order, the products can be interpreted as either matrix multiplication or tensor product. Raising a ket or a bra to a certain power is interpreted as tensor product, since their matrix dimensions don't allow them to be multiplied by themselves using matrix multiplication.

To look at a smaller instance of your example, $|0\rangle^2 \langle 1|^2$ vs $(|0\rangle \langle 1|)^2$, the first one is interpreted as $|00\rangle\langle11|$ (a $4\times4$ matrix, with powers representing tensor products and the product between them acting as outer product), and the second one as $|0\rangle \langle 1||0\rangle \langle 1| = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (a $2\times2$ matrix with all zeros, with $|0\rangle \langle 1|$ being a $2\times2$ matrix and the power representing regular matrix multiplication).